# how to combine two json variables using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Is there  a simple way to combine two json variables?
Given `$a {a:1,b:1}` and `$b {c:1,d:1}`
How do I produce a result of `{a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1}`

Comment: jq are you mean jQuery?

Comment: no https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: Please clarify whether $a is your notation for a bash variable or a jq variable?

Comment: they are just bash variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```sh
a='{"a":1,"b":1}'
b='{"c":1,"d":1}'

jq --slurp 'add' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 1,
  "d": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, e.g.

```
$a + $b
```

or

```
 [$a,$b]|add
```

For example, if $a and $b are initially JSON-valued shell variables:

```
jq -n --argjson a "$a" --argjson b "$b" '$a + $b'
```

Comment: anyway to do with jq?

Comment: That is jq! That’s what you asked for.

Comment: hi @peak, your updated answer might work, I will try!